# Fetch relationship of deleted entity. (Crash)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

On app startup, I am deleting old CoreData rows in a background thread and below is the code that I have. My problem is similar to City-Streets problem. So, I have two entities, Street and City and I have a relationship City <->> Street as a city has many streets.

I got a rare crash on Crashlytics just where it's stated in the code below. The crash never happened to me and I was unable to replicate it. I am not sure if the problem could be that we shouldn't fetch the relationships of a deleted entity. Can someone give me some explanations or the steps to reproduce the issue? (I want to make sure that this is the cause)

```
context.performBlock{
    //fetch the entities I want to delete
    let streets = fetchEntitiesToDeleteInContext(context) 

    for street in streets{
        context.deleteObject(street)

        let city: City = street.city // NO crash here
        let cityName: String = city.name //crash here but I am sure that name is not nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the city object *before* you delete a street.

Also, your code does not make any sense. You are defining variables in the scope of the `for` loop and not using them. - But you explained that this is just an excerpt.

Note that the behavior is *undefined* so it is not *guaranteed* to crash. No need to worry about why it worked before.

Comment: Actually the code is more complex  so I am using the variables nside the for loop. When I got that crash, I noticed that I should have done it the way you said, but why the crash never happened to me and why it's crashing on city.name and not on the deletedObject.city?

Comment: That is called a "false positive". Clearly, if you do something that is not foreseen the result is **undefined**. So it is not *guranteed* to crash. ;-)